# Linking 2 object files?

Tags: assembly, arm

I started out with ARM assembly language recently and have assembled two source files model.s and v_bin.s to model.o and v_bin.o respectively; v_bin.s contains a subroutine, and model.s contains the calling code. I wish to link the two object files to an executable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.globl my_func` to export the symbol `my_func` (defined by a label like `my_func:`) so other files can call your `my_func`.  ([GAS manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Global.html)).

So `ld` can match up a reference to `my_func` in one `.o` with a definition in another `.o`.

Then you can link normally by passing multiple `.o` files to whatever you normally use to link one into a binary.  (e.g. gcc or `ld`)

Without `.globl` on a symbol name you define, it's private to this object file, like C `static` functions and file-scope variables.

Answer (score 0):

Simply if you want to link these two files you can run the following to get this done. Assuming you are using arm-none-eabi toolchain and no library dependency.

```
arm-none-eabi-ld -T your-linker-script.ld -o "app.elf" v_bin.o model.o
```

A good resource is http://www.martinhubacek.cz/arm/arm-cortex-bare-metal-assembly/stm32f0-cortex-m0-bare-metal-assembly Look at the make file the guy has created